# Not able to change the AUTO_DEL_REC_OBJ value to ON

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I changed the value of `AUTO_DEL_REC_OBJ` to `on` as below in UAT and prod environment; in UAT it's done but in prod its current value is still showing `OFF`. What did I do wrong?

In UAT:

```
db2 update db cfg for CMNDB using AUTO_DEL_REC_OBJ ON

 Description                                   Parameter   Current Value              Delayed Value
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Auto deletion of recovery objects    (AUTO_DEL_REC_OBJ) = ON                         ON
```

In Prod:

```
 Description                                   Parameter   Current Value              Delayed Value
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Auto deletion of recovery objects    (AUTO_DEL_REC_OBJ) = OFF                        ON
```

Why has it changed in the UAT server but not in Prod?

Answer (score 0):

You must connect to the database first to change some parameter online, if it's possible for this parameter:

```
db2 connect to CMNDB 
db2 update db cfg using AUTO_DEL_REC_OBJ ON
db2 get db cfg show detail | grep AUTO_DEL_REC_OBJ
```